# TS2307: Cannot find module 'class-validator'

Tags: typescript, gulp, class-validator, gulp-typescript

I'm attempting to use the [class-validator](https://github.com/pleerock/class-validator) module in a typescript project.  However when I compile typescript issues the following warning:

```
src/main/ts/domain/Order.ts(1,48): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'class-validator'.
```

The line it is complaining about looks like this:

```
  import { IsInt, IsNotEmpty, IsDate, Min } from "class-validator";
```

I have gulp setup like this:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
    var tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");

    gulp.task('default', function() {
      return tsProject.src()
        .pipe(tsProject())
        .js.pipe(gulp.dest("target/main/js"));
    });
```

And my tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
    {
        "files": [
            "src/main/ts/**/*.ts"
        ],
        "compilerOptions": {
            "experimentalDecorators": true,
            "noImplicitAny": true,
            "target": "es6"
        }
    }
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set `"moduleResolution": "node"` in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "es6"
  }
}
```

You can find more info on how TypeScript resolves your imported modules here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#node

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me: `yarn add graphql class-validator type-graphql`

Source: https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/issues/625#issuecomment-626368051

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install typescript types for validator in addition to installing class-validator.

That is `npm install @types/validator`

Answer (score 2):

You need ti install class-validator dependency , use this commond:

> `npm install class-validator`

Answer (score 2):

You need to install call-validator and class-transformer packages

```
npm i --save class-validator class-transformer
```