# Cannot find module 'class-validator' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

My problem is that I can't compile the hosted project. An error occurs during compilation. And more specifically:

`src/auth/dto/create-auth.dto.ts:6:8 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'class-validator' or its corresponding type declarations.`

These questions didn't help me:

[TS2307: Cannot find module 'class-validator'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43704619/ts2307-cannot-find-module-class-validator)

[class-validator is peer dependency but seems to be required?](https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/issues/625#issuecomment-626368051)

[How to solve npm error "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/how-to-solve-npm-error-npm-err-code-elifecycle)

the only solution was to add the command:

`npm rub builld --force`

deploy occurs, but the launch itself now fails with an error

I tried many options, but not one of them was suitable, and the error still appears during assembly

hosting:

`render`

build command:

`npm; npm i --save class-validator class-transformer; npm link webpack; npm run build`

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "moduleResolution": "Node"
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "chat",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "",
    "author": "",
    "private": true,
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "nest build",
        "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
        "start": "nest start",
        "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
        "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
        "start:prod": "node dist/main",
        "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
        "test": "jest",
        "test:watch": "jest --watch",
        "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
        "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
        "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@nestjs/class-validator": "^0.13.1",
        "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
        "@nestjs/config": "^3.0.0",
        "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
        "@nestjs/mapped-types": "^2.0.2",
        "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
        "@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^9.4.0",
        "@nestjs/typeorm": "^10.0.0",
        "@nestjs/websockets": "^9.4.0",
        "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
        "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
        "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
        "@types/validator": "^13.7.17",
        "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
        "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
        "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
        "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
        "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
        "hash": "^0.2.1",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
        "nestjs-yup": "^1.0.13",
        "pg": "^8.11.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
        "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
        "socket.io": "^4.7.0",
        "typeorm": "^0.3.17"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@nestjs/cli": "^9.0.0",
        "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.0",
        "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.0",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
        "@types/jest": "29.5.1",
        "@types/node": "^18.16.12",
        "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.61.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.61.0",
        "eslint": "^8.0.1",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
        "jest": "29.5.0",
        "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
        "supertest": "^6.1.3",
        "ts-jest": "29.1.0",
        "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
        "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
        "tsconfig-paths": "4.2.0",
        "typescript": "^5.0.0"
    },
    "jest": {
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "js",
            "json",
            "ts"
        ],
        "rootDir": "src",
        "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
        },
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
            "**/*.(t|j)s"
        ],
        "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
        "testEnvironment": "node"
    }
}
```